# How to avoid SIGSEGV in interactive python console?

Tags: pycharm, python-3.7, itk

I was using `itk` to load a 3d-volume file and got a curious error but only if I ran the code with *Run with Python Console* checked in the Run Configurations in PyCharm. (This runs the program in a python console, which is very convenient if for accessing the variables after the program ran.)

```
import itk

def read_the_image(file_path):
    global image
    itk_image = itk.imread(file_path)
    image = itk.GetArrayViewFromImage(itk_image)
    return image

if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_the_image("./t0.mha")
```

I also noticed that the `global` statement is contributing (without that, it works fine too). It also only happens with certain image types: While it doesn't happen with `.png`s it does happen with `.mha`s. You can find the example of such a file in [this tutorial archive](https://sourceforge.net/projects/plastimatch/files/Sample%20Data/registration-tutorial.tar.gz) (of a project on sourceforge).

So I'd like to understand why this happens in the interactive python console and what I could do to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that avoids this error, but I still don't understand why it occurred in the first place. The key is copying the data into a new image:

```
import itk
import numpy as np

def read_the_image(file_path):
    global image
    itk_image = itk.imread(file_path)
    image = np.copy(itk.GetArrayViewFromImage(itk_image))
    return image

if __name__ == '__main__':
    image = 3
    read_the_image("./t0.mha")
```

I guess the array we get from `itk.GetArrayViewFromImage` accesses some kind of ressource that must be properly closed before the program ends which might not happen when it is ran in the interactive python console.(?) But I still have no idea why this would happen with this particular format.